# Chrome Extension: cannot set property .innerHTML of null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build out my first Chrome Extension, but am running into a frustrating road block. I have seen this question asked before, but the solution of placing the popup.js file after the element in the HTML is still throwing an error.

Does anyone know why I'd be getting the error: **cannot set property .innerHTML of null**, when the element is being clearly defined?

What I did realize is that 'document' refers to the DOM and not the browser extension, as there's no "updateThis" element in the DOM. Maybe my manifest.json file is off?

Thanks in advance for any help here. Seems like a simple issue but I can't get past it.

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Text Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Test.",
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>", "storage"],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["popup.js"],
            "css": ["style.css"],
            "all_frames": true,
            "run_at": "document_idle"

        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById('updateThis').innerHTML = "test value";
});
```

```html
<body style="height:200px; width:350px;">
  <p id="updateThis"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: When I converted your code to a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) (which you should do), the code example works... what are you seeing instead?

Comment: Thanks for replying! I am seeing the Popup Title only in the Chrome Extension, nothing in the body of the Chrome Extension window. Wondering if the manifest.json is off or wrong?

Comment: Popup title? You are asking about "test value" not the title.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation provided by [Google](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time)

> The browser chooses a time to inject scripts between "document_end"
> and immediately after the window.onload event fires. The exact moment
> of injection depends on how complex the document is and how long it is
> taking to load, and is optimized for page load speed.
>
> Content scripts running at "document_idle" do not need to listen for
> the window.onload event, they are guaranteed to run after the DOM is
> complete. If a script definitely needs to run after window.onload, the
> extension can check if onload has already fired by using the
> document.readyState property.

Setting the runtime to `document_idle` means that your script will only run after document loaded event so listening to the event `DOMContentLoaded` is not needed. The reason you are not able to get the element `#updateThis` is because the html is not injected into the page at all.

You are confusing content scripts with popup scripts. Content scripts are injected into every page (and every frame if configured in manifest) whereas popup scripts will only run when the [browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) icon is clicked.

It all depends on what are you trying to achieve in your extension.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work in the stack snippet as you can see below. Instead of `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"...` try `window.addEventListener("load"...`

The difference here is that it will wait for the entire page to load rather than just the DOM.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    document.getElementById('updateThis').innerHTML = "test value";

})


// consider using window        instead of document
//                querySelector instead of getElementById
//               .textContent   instead of .innerHTML

// window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
//     document.querySelector('#updateThis').textContent = "test value";
// });
```

```html
<p id="updateThis"></p>
```